# SQL query - counting what is not there

Tags: mysql, sql

I collect thermostat data every 5min. Now I would like to know how many hours per day the heater is on. I do this with this query:

```
$sql = "SELECT round((COUNT(*)*5)/60,1) as Counter, date(timestamp) as WeekDay, Heating  
FROM `rawdata` 
WHERE Heating = 1 
GROUP BY DAY(timestamp);";
```

Works fine and gives me back the hours of the day, IF it was on for that day. For my graphs that I build on this data however, it would be better if I got a row in return with date and the value 0. In other words, I would need a row returned for each day.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I normally have a table of 'days' and left or right join on that.

Comment: What @csmu said. This type of table, with the intervals already filled in, is known as a "pivot" table.